# Kubernetes Connection error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have installed the kubernetes as per the document and I am using Mac V10.13

while I run `kubectl version` or `kubectl cluster-info`

I get this error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I've looked many solutions but didn't fine one working, does anyone got the solution for this?

Comment: Can you link the url to the document you were using for installation? This error usually means that your kubectl can't talk to api server, so either server is not where kubectl is expecting it or not running properly...

Comment: solved it with minikube. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run Kubectl you have to configure the admin.conf:

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23726